# Is it necessary to use AnnotationConfiguration for Hibernate Configuration?

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations, reverse-engineering, hibernate-mapping

I want to use Configuration() methot. But I get this error:

```
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.MappingException: An AnnotationConfiguration instance is required to use <mapping class="com.example.domain.Lesson"/>
```

If I use AnnotationConfiguratin() method, Hibernate can read my classes. I don't understand this:

Why when I use Configuration method, Hibernate can't see `<mapping class="com.example.Lesson"/>` definition?

My `hibernate.cfg.xml` file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>

        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">****</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/DB</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">postgres</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>   

        <mapping resource="com.example/Lesson.hbm.xml" /> 

        <mapping class="com.example.Lesson"/>


    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

My Lesson class :

```
    public class Lesson implements java.io.Serializable {

        private int id;
        private String lesson;
        private Set lessons = new HashSet(0);

        public Lesson() {
        }


        public Lesson(int id, String lesson, Set lessons) {
            this.id = id;
            this.id = id;
            this.lessons = lessons;
        }


        continue..



}
```

I had bhm.xml files from `reverse engineering.` So, I don't want to use Annotation.

Any idea?

Comment: Show us `com.example.domain.Lesson` class source. It seems that is contains some hibernate annotations.

Comment: I added. Lesson class's source is not contain hibernate annotations.

Comment: Ok. I have not carefully read your question. It seems to me, that the problem is with `<mapping class="com.example.Lesson"/>` statement in `hibernate.cfg.xml`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove `<mapping class="com.example.Lesson"/>` from `hibernate.cfg.xml`. It is not necessary because `Lesson.hbm.xml` is present.